# How to manipulate OpenStreetMap schema to be useful in ArcGIS applications?

Tags: python, openstreetmap, arcgis-engine, schema-architecture

I have a shapefile of OSM data. I plan to use the data for an ArcGIS Engine application, and I was wondering if there are any existing solutions to getting the data's schema into your typical GIS format. What I'm talking about is the "tags" attribute. It contains a comma-separated list of categories and their values, whereas typically you would see these values as separate fields in a feature class.

**Are there any tools available that separate the tag values out into separate fields?** It would probably be straightforward to create a Python script that separates these out, but I'd like to know if a solution already exists before I create one myself.

Answer (score 2):

**OpenStreetMap Loader for ArcGIS**

There is a geoprocessing script tool that will load the openstreetmap xml planet dump file into a file geodatabase. It works directly against the compressed *.bz2 file. It is a Python script and toolbox, designed to load the data without using too much memory whatever the size of the source data. The script has been updated to support the new xml format of openstreetmap.

You can convert out to a shapefile after the import to file geodatabase.

Source:
ArcScripts
http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=15137